# Is it normal to describe someone as having white skin?

Tags: word-choice

Is it normal, outside of the context of discussing a person's race, albinism, or very artificial make-up, to describe someone as having white skin, as opposed to using words such as "pale" or "light-coloured"?

The context it was used was an East Asian person describing another person of the same ethnicity in terms of how beautiful she is.

Comment: Not enough context.  Describing the skin's color generally, or, as Beta Decay suggests, describing its appearance under special circumstances (e.g. sudden fear, shock, illness)?

Comment: @TRomano good point - I've added context.

Comment: "white" can be neutral (or apparently, in your example, positive). "pale" has a negative connotation; people's faces get "pale" when they are feeling faint.  "ashen" is even worse, and  "pallid" might be used to describe a corpse. To me, "cream" or "ivory" seem like a healthier sort of white. And both suggest smoothness as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly normal, for example:

> My God, you've gone white...Are you okay?

Light-coloured isn't really used to describe the abnormal colour of someone's skin, but pale is a good alternative to white.

Answer (score 2):

In the days when many people worked in the field, the field-workers were exposed to a lot of sun.  They would be swarthy, ruddy and tanned.

Posh ladies had no need to be out in the sun all day - so pale skin became a signifier of wealth and/or status.

Nowadays it's almost the opposite - most people work indoors in offices away from natural sunlight.  The way to get a tan is often to jet far off to hot sunny climes for a holiday.  The tan becomes a signifier of having the means to holiday somewhere a tan can be acquired.

Ruddy complexions were often seen as a good thing for a peasant.

"Alabaster skin" was often sought after.

Comment: +1 for this answer, as although it seems to refer to the positive associations of white skin in European history, this perception is also a contemporary one in parts of Asia (where the person using the term originates according to the OP), i.e. pale skin denotes a higher status due to not having to work outside in the sun.

Comment: As a historical aside, white skin was once so sought after that 18th century Europeans would use makeup made from "white lead" to lighten their skins - this was toxic and damaged the skin, eyes and teeth and caused lead poisoning.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not usual. We might say *ivory*.

Answer (score -2):

Describing someone as having white skin is not normal or even nice. That's pretty racist if you ask me. A better way to describe "People with white skin" is by saying "the Caucasian person", not "white".

Comment: The question specifically pointed out that this was *outside* the context of race. Pointing out that someone's skin is, in fact, remarkably close to the shade of a piece of paper can be rude at times, depending on the situation and the way it's described, but it need not be considered taboo.